# TypeError: not indexable

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

when trying to print a variables passed in as `x` which contains elements from a text field to my python script via ajax, it prompts me with the error `TypeError: not indexable`

I have tried storing the FieldStorage value in a different variable then printing :

```
post = cgi.FieldStorage()
thing = post.getvalue("x")
print thing
```

but it still prompts me with the same error

here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.py',
    cache: false,
    contentType:"application/text-plain; charset=utf-8",
    data: {
        "x": $("input#name").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("p#second").text(data);

    },
    error: function(data){
        $("p#second").text("ya sorry nah");
    }

});
```

exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/main/code/test.py", line 12, in &lt;module&gt; thing = post.getvalue("x") File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 548, in getvalue if key in self: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 594, in __contains__ raise TypeError, "not indexable" TypeError: not indexable -->
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate i have added the exact error

Comment: Why are you setting the content type to plain text? Why are you setting it at all? (And why are you using cgi, but that's a separate question.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have not used ajax before so looking at other peoples scripts i thought it was necessary, but now I took it out and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielRoseman mentioned you do not need the `contentType` in your ajax code.